# How do I convert a JSONB value to boolean in Postgresql?

Tags: json, postgresql

What is the best way to convert a boolean field from a JSONB object into a normal bool type in Postgres?

For example I have a JSON object `{"foo": true}`, which I can use in Postgresql. E.g.: `select ('{"foo": true}'::jsonb);` which gives me something of type JSONB.

Now I want to extract the `foo` field as a boolean. If I do:

```
select ('{"foo": true}'::jsonb)->'foo';
```

I get back something of type JSONB.

But, I can't cast JSONB to boolean. If instead of I do:

```
select ('{"foo": true}'::jsonb)->>'foo';
```

I will get back something of type string. From that I can convert to a boolean. (E.g:)

```
select (('{"foo": true}'::jsonb)->>'foo')::bool;
```

But that seems a bit icky going from internal representation to string, and then back to another internal representation.

Is there any to go directly to a bool?

My other current best work around seems to be:

```
select (('{"foo": true}'::jsonb)->'foo') = 'true'::jsonb;
```

but that also seems a bit wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`json_to_record`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html):

```
select foo
from json_to_record('{"foo": true}') as x(foo bool);
```

I am not sure if that really saves you any internal casts, but it's the closest thing I know of in 9.4